# Calculate empty space of a polygon

Tags: math, geometry, openlayers

I'm currently working on a project in Openlayers where we allow the users to draw polygon-shapes. These shapes are only allowed to be drawn inside another polygon which for clarity i will call the Trackable-Area. To meet one of the requirements of the customer, i need to find the empty space of the Trackable-Area. I've already achieved finding the area size of the empty space, but i am lost on how to calculate the empty space as a polygon.

Please see the following picture as an example. The "rectangle" is the Trackable-Area polygon, and the colorful shapes are the drawn polygons made by the user. The white space is what i aim to calculate as another polygon.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this by creating a multipolygon containing all drawn polygons, and then utilizing the JSTS-library to calculate the difference between the multipolygon and trackable-area polygon:

```
// map JSTS GeoJSON-readers
const jstsGeoJSONReader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();
const jstsGeoJSONWriter = new jsts.io.GeoJSONWriter();
// ol GeoJSON-format
const geoJSONFormat = new GeoJSON();
let trackableAreaFeature;
let trackableAreaGeomJSTS;

// trackable area geometry parsed to JSTS
const TrackableAreaLayer = this.mapService.getLayerByName(LAYERS.TRACKABLE_AREA);
trackableAreaFeature = TrackableAreaLayer.getSource().getFeatureById('Trackable Area');
trackableAreaGeomJSTS = jstsGeoJSONReader.read(geoJSONFormat.writeFeatureObject(trackableAreaFeature)).geometry;

// create multiPolygon consisting of drawn zones
const multiPolygon = new MultiPolygon([]);
const zoneSource = drawnAreaLayer.getSource();
const zoneFeatures = drawnAreaLayer.getSource().getFeatures();

zoneFeatures.forEach(zone => {
  const zoneGeometry = zone.getGeometry();
  multiPolygon.appendPolygon(zoneGeometry);
});

// parse multipolygon to JSTS
const multiPolygonJSTS = jstsGeoJSONReader.read(geoJSONFormat.writeGeometry(multiPolygon));

// calculate difference between trackable area and multipolygon
const unmappedAreaJSTS = trackableAreaGeomJSTS.difference(multiPolygonJSTS);
const unmappedAreaGeometry = jstsGeoJSONWriter.write(unmappedAreaJSTS);

// parse multipolygon from GeoJSON to ol geometry
const unmappedAreaMultiPolygonGeometry = geoJSONFormat.readGeometry(unmappedAreaGeometry);

// create ol feature based on parsed geometry
const unmappedAreaFeature = new Feature({
  geometry: unmappedAreaMultiPolygonGeometry
});

// add Feature to source of layer
zoneSource.addFeature(unmappedAreaFeature);
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to delete de area of the trackable area (`T`) with the summed area of all the polygons drawn by the user inside the trackable area (`S`).

`E = T - S`, where `E` is the empty area.

En the newest version fo the library, you just need to use the function `getArea` ([OL API Docs - Polygon getArea](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon-Polygon.html#getArea)).

Comment: Thank you, that would also be a solution. I've used the JSTS library to calculate the difference and posted this as a separate answer.